# How do I handle these typedef's without warnings?

Tags: c, type-conversion, warnings, typedef

I have some if statements to handle the value_type in different ways. If `INT` is defined then `value_type` is an integer, but if `CHAR` is defined `value_typ`e is a string. How can I handle this so I don' get any errors or warnings ?

I defined `value_type` like this:

```
#ifdef INT
typedef int value_type;
#define TYPEMODE 1
#endif

#ifdef CHAR
typedef char value_type[80];
#define TYPEMODE -1
#endif
```

I handled it like this in functions:

```
int functionName(value_type val) {
   if (TYPEMODE == 1) {
      val = 5;
   }
   if (TYPEMODE == -1) {
      strcpy(val, "hi");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

If I define `INT` it gives me a warning for `strcpy`, if I define `CHAR` it gives me a warning for `val = 5`.

Is there a better way to handle this that won't give me any warnings with `gcc -Wall file.c -o file`?

Comment: What is `val = 5` supposed to achieve? Is `int` here supposed to be `int*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int functionName(value_type val) {
   if (TYPEMODE == 1) {
      val = 5;
   }
   if (TYPEMODE == -1) {
      strcpy(val, "hi");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

can be

```
int functionName(value_type val) {
#if TYPEMODE == 1
      val = 5;
#endif
#if TYPEMODE == -1
      strcpy(val, "hi");
#endif
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should modify both code fragments this way:

In the declaration file:

```
#ifdef INT
typedef int value_type;
#define TYPEMODE  1
#endif

#ifdef CHAR
typedef char value_type[80];
#define TYPEMODE  (-1)   // use parentheses to avoid operator precedence issues
#endif
```

In the code:

```
int functionName(value_type val) {
#if TYPEMODE == 1
   val = 5;
#elif TYPEMODE == -1
   strcpy(val, "hi");
#endif
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're flagging on preprocessor flags, it's best to let the preprocessor do the check:

```
int functionName(value_type val) {
#if TYPEMODE == 1
    val = 5;
#elif TYPEMODE == -1
    strcpy(val, "hi");
#endif
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer an alternative option: have you considered ditching the `#defines` and just using a `union`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
    int number;
    char text[50];
} value_type;

void functionName(value_type val, int typemode) {
    if (typemode == 1) {
        val.number = 5;
    } else if (typemode == -1) {
        strcpy(val.text, "hi");
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    value_type myval;
    functionName(myval, 1);
    functionName(myval, -1);
    return 0;
}
```